# When I build iOS a flutter project it shows an error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

When I build iOS a flutter project it shows an error
The project is working successfully on Android but it fails on iOS

The same error appears when I build on Android studio and Xcode

Attached is a picture of the error and a text file with the error, exported from the Xcode

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19oH9AVPcOtvntLpoa9CgB4WhqnScaeC3/view?usp=sharing

[image: error]

Comment: did you run flutter pub get before building for each platform?

Comment: did you run flutter pub get before building for each platform?

Comment: is this a fresh project or does it contain some dependencies already?

Comment: I applied all these commands

flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod install
pod update
flutter build ios --release  

and this project content many dependencies

Comment: Clear Xcode cache using `Shift+Command+k`
Then install pod and then rebuild

Answer (score 1):

i think the iOS project has crashed, make a backup of your current project, delete the iOS folder and reinitialize it.

go to the project folder and run the following command

```
flutter create -i swift .
```

then run `flutter run` and check again.

Comment: When run this command and run on device show this error

Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability

Comment: What kind of packages are you using

Comment: What do you mean by packages type?

Comment: No, in your pubspec.yaml file, what kind of packages did you import.. there might be a package you imported that doesn't support iOS

Comment: I don't think so, it used to work on iOS before

Comment: Yep, only solution that worked after keep getting random errors and wasting time solving them.